# streaming video file using vlcj

Tags: java, video-streaming, http-streaming, vlcj

I am trying to play a video file ..but getting few errors , 
not sure how to solve these errors , can anybody help me out please, thanks in advance

```
   `Streaming 'C:\Desktop\movie.mp4' to ':sout=#duplicate{dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=127.0.0.1:5555}}'
       _       _
__   _| | ___ (_)
\ \ / / |/ __|| |
 \ V /| | (__ | |
  \_/ |_|\___|/ | 2.2.0
            |__/  www.capricasoftware.co.uk

VLCJ is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

VLCJ is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with VLCJ.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

Copyright 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012 Caprica Software Limited.

vlcj: (Info.java:103)                                | INFO  | vlcj: <version not available>
vlcj: (Info.java:104)                                | INFO  | java: 1.6.0_23 Sun Microsystems Inc.
vlcj: (Info.java:105)                                | INFO  | java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
vlcj: (Info.java:106)                                | INFO  | os: Windows 7 6.1 x86
vlcj: (LibVlcFactory.java:164)                       | INFO  | vlc: 2.0.1 Twoflower, changeset 2.0.1-0-gf432547
vlcj: (LibVlcFactory.java:165)                       | INFO  | libvlc: libvlc.dll
[04451750] access_output_http access out: Consider passing --http-host=IP on the command line instead.
[002c9648] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[04430e28] main mux error: cannot add this stream
[04424528] main decoder error: cannot create packetizer output (theo)
[04430e28] main mux error: cannot add this stream
[056d0c80] main decoder error: cannot create packetizer output (vorb)
`
```

Comment: i got it working i just change the String [] options that i was passing and it works perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have change the string to this and it works fine ..........

```
String[] options = {" :dshow-vdev=ip Camera :dshow-adev=  :dshow-caching=200", ":sout = #transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,scale=0.25,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:display :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep"};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a faster choice:

```
String[] options = {
      ":dshow-adev=none",
      ":dshow-vdev=",
      ":dshow-aspect-ratio=4\\:3",
      ":live-caching=200",
      ":sout-mp4-faststart",
      ":dshow-size=640x480",
      ":sout=#duplicate{dst=display,dst='transcode{vcodec=x264,venc=x264,vb=1000,fps=1,scale=1,width=640,height=480}:standard{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=C:\\xy.mp4}'}"
    };
```